# Uninstalling a plugin that was installed through a Vimball

Tags: vimball

I came across a plugin for vim and it comes in a .vmb file. Currently I use pathogen and it's quite simple I place the downloaded files into the bundle folder and it gets picked up automagically (in a sense). I am not sure about a vmb based plugin. So far in order to install it I found this regarding installing a .vmb plugin

> The easiest way to install SuperTab is to grab the file supertab.vmb
>   (which is an archive called a “vimball”) and place it into your
>   “~/.vim/bundle” directory. Then open it in Vim and source the file:
>
> vim supertab.vmb :so %

My question is how would I go about deleting this plugin if i did not want it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `:RmVimball` command. From [`:help :RmVimball`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_vimball.txt.html#%3aRmVimball)

```
REMOVING A VIMBALL                      :RmVimball

        :RmVimball vimballfile [path]

    This command removes all files generated by the specified vimball
    (but not any directories it may have made).  One may choose a path
    for de-installation, too (see 'runtimepath'); otherwise, the
    default is the first existing directory on the 'runtimepath'.
    To implement this, a file (.VimballRecord) is made in that directory
    containing a record of what files need to be removed for all vimballs
    used thus far.
```

Note that you an also install it to a specific path with [`:UseVimball`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pi_vimball.txt.html#%3aUseVimball)

```
MANUALLY INVOKING VIMBALL EXTRACTION                :UseVimball

        :UseVimball [path]

    This command is contained within the vimball itself; it invokes the
    vimball#Vimball() routine which is responsible for unpacking the
    vimball.  One may choose to execute it by hand instead of sourcing
    the vimball; one may also choose to specify a path for the
    installation, thereby overriding the automatic choice of the first
    existing directory on the 'runtimepath'.
```

So if you want to install a vimball to `~/.vim/bundle/plugin` so it will be loaded with pathogen instead of `~/.vim` you can use this.

Comment: Thanks for the post , I got a little confused here .Say If I want to load a vimball with pathogen do I use the `UseVimball` command ? so place the vimball (say xyz.vmb) in `~/vim/bundle/plugin` and then do a `:UseVimball xyz` ?

Comment: See `:help g:vimball_home`.

Comment: @JamesFranco `Say If I want to load a vimball with pathogen do I` -- check the entry `What about Vimballs?`at [pathogen FAQ](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen#faq)